# Why doesn't opening a moved tab in a new window work in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

When I drag a tab out of the main window of Visual Studio Code, it should by default open in a new window. However, this is not happening. I have investigated the issue but have not found a solution. Why isn't it working?

Update: I came back to this topic after a long time. Visual Studio Code has brought this support with its new update. I wanted to share this information with you. November 2023 (version 1.85) you can find details from the link below.

Floating editor windows: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_floating-editor-windows

Comment: This question does not belong to [so], it is not about programming. Ask on [VSCode issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's impossible.
See here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121

It's the most upvoted issue in the VS code repository, it's open since 2016, but sadly there is no progress.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, I thought I wrote you a thank you answer. There was an update to the question I asked and this support was added to VS Code. I mentioned this in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to come back to this topic after a long time because Visual Studio Code brought this support with its new update. I wanted to share this information with you. [November 2023 (version 1.85)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85) you can find details from the link below.

Floating editor windows: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_workbench